# Cannot assign must be a "" instance

Tags: django, django-models

i'm working on my first django project and i got this error 
(Cannot assign "'433245675'": "Lockers.locker_id" must be a "Renters" instance.)
anyone here can help me pleas.

the views:

```
def adding_renter(request):
    form_data = forms.AddingRenter(request.POST or None)
    msg = ''
    if form_data.is_valid():
        renters = models.Renters()
        renters.renter_id = form_data.cleaned_data['renter_id']
        renters.renter_name = form_data.cleaned_data['renter_name']
        renters.renter_email = form_data.cleaned_data['renter_email']
        renters.renter_phone_number = form_data.cleaned_data['renter_phone_number']
        renters.renting_start_date = form_data.cleaned_data['renting_start_date']
        renters.renting_end_date = form_data.cleaned_data['renting_end_date']
        renters.save()
        msg = 'Renter has been added successfully'
    context = {
        'form': form_data,
        'msg': msg
    }
    return rend
```

er(request, 'addingrenter.html', context)

```
def adding_locker(request):
    form_data = forms.AddingLocker(request.POST or None)
    msg = ''
    if form_data.is_valid():
        lockers = models.Lockers()
        lockers.locker_id = form_data.cleaned_data['locker_id']
        lockers.locker_number = form_data.cleaned_data['locker_number']
        lockers.locker_information = form_data.cleaned_data['locker_information']
        lockers.locker_status = form_data.cleaned_data['locker_status']
        lockers.locker_notes = form_data.cleaned_data['locker_notes']
        lockers.save()
        msg = 'Locker has been added successfully'
    context = {
        'form': form_data,
        'msg': msg
    }
    return render(request, 'addinglocker.html', context)
```

Comment: It might be beneficial to share your Lockers model and perhaps how you received this error as well. Fails to reach form view or after submitting the form?

Comment: i got the error after submitting the form, when i submit it from django i get no error, but when i submit from my html page i got this error.

Comment: @HamadNasser as plum 0 has mentioned, you should share your Locker model, because right now its structure isn't clear and the error make it seem like your Locker model has a ForeignKey relationship with your Renters model.

Comment: class Renters(models.Model):
    renter_id = models.IntegerField(default=1, unique=True)
    renter_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

Comment: i cannot share the rest of the model because the characters limit, but i hope i shared the important part of it.

Comment: .... anyone please help

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess you have the field named as `locker_id`. If that's the case, the actual ID field is named `locker_id_id`. So try using:

```
lockers.locker_id_id = form_data.cleaned_data['locker_id']
```

Though your error makes it seem like your model is defined as:

```
class Renters(models.Model):
    ...

class Lockers(models.Model):
    locker_id = models.ForeignKey(Renters)
```

Instead it should be:

```
class Renter(models.Model): # Models should be singular
    ...

class Locker(models.Model):
    renter = models.ForeignKey(Renter)
```